# How do I get Pip to work with Python3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I'm running `Ubuntu 12.04` and do not have the option of upgrading / using something else. It has `Python3.2` on it. I have found out that `pip` doesn't come automatically with < 3.4. How can I get `pip` to work with `Python3` on this machine?

I tried downloading a copy of `get-pip.py` and running it with `python3.2`, but I kept getting an error message about how < 3.4 support was dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a little bit getting this all to work so I wanted to make a detailed post.

First I found out I could get `Python3.4` onto my `Ubuntu 12.04` machine. To do this run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.4
```

Source: [Is There An Easy Way To Install Python 34 On](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/20xims/is_there_an_easy_way_to_install_python_34_on/)

Next, I removed `Python3.2` (I only wanted to have a single Python3.x version on my machine) by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3.2
sudo apt-get remove python3.2-minimal
```

Then, to get `pip` I ran:

```
sudo curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
sudo python3.4 get-pip.py
```

Source: [How To Install Pip On Ubuntu 12 04 LTS](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/)

At this point `Python3.4` and `pip` can both be ran. Example:

```
python3.4 main.py
pip3 install requests
```

At this point I wanted to be able to just use `python3` to run `python3.4` - trying just `python3` kept telling me I had to install `python-minimal`. Doing this reinstalled `python3.2` for me which I did not want. Instead, I created an `alias` by doing the following:

```
vim ~/.bashrc # Open the file for editing
```

Add: `alias python3=python3.4` to the file.

```
. ~/.bashrc # Make the changes apply to the current session
```

Source: [How Do I Create A Permanent Bash Alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)